# Load image formURL using a Thread

Tags: android

How should I load an image from http using a `Thread` in android?
I would like to show the layout while waiting the image to load.

Now I'm using this code to show my img from http, and it show a dark blank screen for a few time  before show the result:

```
        private Drawable ImageOperations(Context ctx, String url, String saveFilename) {
        try {
            InputStream is = (InputStream) this.fetch(url);
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
            return d;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public Object fetch(String address) throws MalformedURLException,IOException {
        URL url = new URL(address);
        Object content = url.getContent();
        return content;
    }
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please fix your question. Even if your English isn't the best, you can fix your language a bit (Typos, missing spaces, start your sentences with a capital letter, end it with a '.', etc.). And what does `<ASK>` mean? Is that some sort of hint that you are asking a question? That's not neccessairy I believe...

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, yeah I know there are many less from me. keep learning

Answer (score 2):

```
Use this for load images from http

ImageView img_item;
String image_url = "here url"
    new Thread(new Runnable() 
    {
    public void run() 
        {
        try 
        {
            final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(image_url).getContent());
            img_item.post(new Runnable()
            {
              public void run() 
              {
                if(bitmap !=null)
                {
                   img_item.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }   
              }
            }); 
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
        // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
  }).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

you should pass your ImageView object to your method. and method run as a thread.